# p:commandLink - get action from controller

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink

I have a `p:commandLink` and would like to make it so that the controller decides its action, based on a parameter.

That's what I have:

```
<p:commandLink 
    action="#{controller.getAction(rownum)}" 
    title="Go"
    styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh centered" 
    ajax="false"
    disabled="#{controller.isLinkDisabled(rownum)}">

    <f:param name="controllerId" value="#{otherController.getId()}" />

</p:commandLink>
```

`rownum` is the `rowIndexVar` of the `p:dataTable` the button is in.

The controller method is:

```
public String getAction(Integer id) {
    if(id == 0) {
        LOG.info("Id is 0"); //LOG is a log4j logger
        return "toDestinationOne";
    } else {
        LOG.info("Id is not 0");
        return "toDestinationTwo";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work.

If I press the button in the first row of the dataTable, in the log I see

```
Id is 0
```

So it means that the method gets called correctly, but for some reason it's ignoring the returned value, the page gets simply refreshed, I'm not getting redirected to the new page.

Both strings are in the `faces-config.xml`:

```
<navigation-case>
    <description>To destination one</description>
    <from-action>toDestinationOne</from-action>
    <from-outcome>toDestinationOne</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/pages/destinationOne.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
    <description>To destination two</description>
    <from-action>toDestinationTwo</from-action>
    <from-outcome>toDestinationTwo</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/pages/destinationTwo.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

If I directly put the value instead, it works properly.

I mean, this:

```
<p:commandLink 
    action="toDestinationOne" 
    title="Go"
    styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh centered" 
    ajax="false"
    disabled="#{controller.isLinkDisabled(rownum)}">

    <f:param name="controllerId" value="#{otherController.getId()}" />

</p:commandLink>
```

Works properly, I get succesfully redirected to the desired page.

So, is there a way to make the `commandLink` follow the `action` returned by the `getAction` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The from-action has to be the same as the action attribute of the commandLink, in your case

```
#{controller.getAction(rownum)}
```

Comment: `#{controller.getAction(rownum)}` refers to a method that can return two different actions, it's not the action string...

Comment: I mean that one:  <p:commandLink action="#{controller.getAction(rownum)}"

Comment: Note (to BackSlash): the getAction() method returns two different -outcomes-. Don't confuse that with it being two different -actions-.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I didn't know it could be done this way. Thank you both! :)